# Getting "Expected 2 arguments but found 1" when getting the intExtra on the Activity result. Not sure what's wrong here

Tags: java, android

I am doing the homework exercise from googles "Android fundamentals codelab" here ->

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-create-an-activity/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#11

and I keep getting this:

```
Expected 2 arguments but found 1
```

error when I try to get the `intExtra` on the Activity result method. I'll post the code below

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == TEXT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            count = data.getIntExtra(HelloActivity.EXTRA_REPLY);
            mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs on line 40 (`count = data.getIntExtra(HelloActivity.EXTRA_REPLY);`).

I know there are other questions here that ask something similar but I am a beginner on Android and java in general so it is difficult for me to understand those solutions in a way that is useful for my problem. a Layman's terms explanation would also be greatly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your code as code in your question. Also read [ask] and [mre]. It will help you to improve your chances at getting answers to your questions. As for your question, read the documentation of [the method your are trying to use](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using requires 2 parameters:

```
getIntExtra(String name, int defaultValue)
```

So, just add a second int parameter, specifying the default value, in case the `name` is not found, something like this:

```
int defaultValue = -1;
count = data.getIntExtra(HelloActivity.EXTRA_REPLY, defaultValue);
```